# Issues with achieving equal height columns using DIV position relative and top as a %

Tags: css, html

Some caveats: no float solutions please unless there's a way to prevent float from going "under" when the screen is minimised.

Also, I'd very much prefer to use % rather than px. Thanks in advance!

My preferred code will go something like this (it doesn't work though):

```
.col {
position: relative; 
width: 20%; 
height:100%;}

<div style="width: 960px; height: 1000px;">
   <div class="col">Column 1</div>
   <div class="col" style="left:20%; top:-100%;">Column 2</div>
   <div class="col" style="left:40%; top:-200%;">Column 3</div>
   <div class="col" style="left:60%; top:-300%;">Column 4</div>
   <div class="col" style="left:80%; top:-400%;">Column 5</div>
</div>
```

As mentioned, this doesn't have the effect I was after. However, if I changed top from % to px, it works.

Example:

```
<div style="width: 960px; height: 1000px;">
   <div class="col">Column 1</div>
   <div class="col" style="left:20%; top:-500px;">Column 2</div>
   <div class="col" style="left:40%; top:-1000px;">Column 3</div>
   <div class="col" style="left:60%; top:-1500px;">Column 4</div>
   <div class="col" style="left:80%; top:-2000px;">Column 5</div>
</div>
```

Where am I going wrong? Left works fine but top doesn't...!

<strike>Ok, to reiterate what I'm after, I want 5 equal height columns, side by side, using % and not px, without using float unless float can be used without any movement in the columns when the screen is resized.</strike>

Thanks again!

UPDATE - I guess the thing that's really bugging me is why left % works so nicely, but top % doesn't.

Comment: You could define a min-height and a max-height but that way they wont be always the same height

Comment: You might want to consider taking a look at the `display: table-cell;` prperties and how it can help you here.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of what you want?

Comment: literally just 5 columns -> |  |  |  |  |  |

Comment: thanks for the tip reg table-cell.